# How can I change the font in my ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to change the font, but I can't do it on Chrome or Samsung A50, Android XI device. I will appreciate any help you can guide me, thanks!

```
Ionic CLI: 6.19.0
Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 6.0.4
Cordova CLI: 11.0.0
```

I copied the ttf in the folder assets/fonts, PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf

```
global.scss: 
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    src: url('/src/assets/fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf')
}
```

---

```
home.scss:
ion-content h3 {
    --ion-font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive !important;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

---

```
home.html: 
<ion-content class="ion-padding" [style.background-image]="'url(' + img_backg + ')'">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-col>
        <h3>{{global.titulo_principal}}</h3>
………
```

Comment: have you unzipped the fonts when you pasted in the fonts folder?

Comment: I only copied the ttf in the folder assets/fonts, PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf

Comment: can you share the full path of the file?

Comment: C:\IONIC6\my_proyect\src\assets\fonts

Comment: (Written with vstudio autocomplete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that home.html is correct, change the path of global.scss to the following:

```
src: url('../assets/fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf')
```

Comment: thanks, I wrote the path like this, but...C:\IONIC6\my_proyect\src\global.scss:16:13: Can't resolve '../assets/fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf' in C:\IONIC6\my_proyect\src'

Being at the same level as global.scss, I wrote it like this, no error but it doesn't work either
src: url('assets/fonts/PermanentMarker-Regular.ttf')

Comment: @Guille can you remove the quotation mark from  'Permanent Marker' to be Permanent Marker

Comment: I removed quotes only from global.scss. It does not work. I removed quotes from global.scss and home.scss at the same time, either.

Comment: the import was missing......thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c';
  src: url('assets/fonts/MPLUSRounded1c-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}

:root {
  --ion-font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}
```

after adding the font to the assets folder. I know this might not be the "go-to" way to do this but it worked and thus I will keep it like this until I notice any problems.